# Selecionar md-option com ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Tenho uma página listando algumas vagas para trabalho. Abaixo destas vagas possuo um formulário e nesse formulário existe um campo de opção para selecionar a vaga de interesse. Caso o usuário clique na vaga de interesse acima, automaticamente no formulário esta opção deve estar marcada no select. Alguém já precisou fazer algo semelhante?
Pois não tenho ideia de como posso fazer isto.

Na área de vagas possuo somente um json com o nome e a descrição de cada vaga;

Segue código abaixo:

Html:

```
<li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="v in vm.vagas">
    <div class="conteudo">
        <div class="titulo">
            <h2>
                {{v.nome}}
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="descricao">
            <p ng-bind-html="v.descricao | trustAs">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="botao">
            <md-button class="btn_padrao verde hvr-radial-out interesse_btn" ng-click="vm.rolar_formulario(v.nome)">
                Estou interessado
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>

<form class="formulario_trabalhe">
    <md-input-container class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no_left">
        <md-select ng-model="vm.form.cargo" placeholder="Cargo pretendido">
                <md-option ng-repeat="c in vm.vagas" value="{{c.nome}}">{{c.nome}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
vm.vagas = [
            {
                'nome' : 'Auxiliar de serviços gerais',
                'descricao' : '<p>Atuar na área de limpeza, varrer o chão, verificar os materiais de limpeza e demais atividades da função.Desejável experiência na área de limpeza.Ensino Fundamental completo.</p>',
            },
            {
                'nome' : 'Fiscal de limpeza',
                'descricao' : '<p>Aferir cartão ponto, atender funcionários e clientes nos postos de trabalho, remanejamento de funcionários, faltas, férias e demais atividades relacionada ao setor.</p>',
            },
            {
                'nome' : 'Cozinheiro',
                'descricao' : '<p>Atuar no preparo de alimentos, organização do local entre outras atividades.Necessário experiência na área.Ensino Médio completo.</p>',
            }
        ]


 vm.rolar_formulario = function(a){
        $timeout(function() {
            $(".interesse_btn").click(function (){
                $('html , body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.determinado').last().offset().top
                });
            });
        });
        console.log(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade é bem simples de resolver essa questão. No botão você realizou a chamada da função **ng-click="vm.rolar_formulario(v.nome)"**, passando como parâmetro pelo que entendi o nome da vaga.

No seu select a variável model **ng-model="vm.form.cargo"** pelo que entendi também está armazenando o nome da vaga, pois é isso que está setado na propriedade **value="{{c.nome}}"**.

Sabendo disso você só precisa fazer algo desse tipo na função:

```
vm.rolar_formulario = function(nomeVaga){
    vm.form.cargo = nomeVaga;
}
```

Só uma dica a mais, na tag md-option tente usar ng-value ao invés de value, só por uma questão de convenção.